# Color value transparency

Tags: android

Is there a way to modify a color value's transparency (and not creating another value)? For example, I have this color value:

```
<color name="blue">#002eff</color>
```

I know that I can give this color a transparency of 50% by appending `80` to the color, like `#80002eff`, but can I use the value's name instead (`blue`)?

Comment: can you elaborate a little on your question? what is your end goal - i couldnt understand from your question.

Comment: Yes use use opacity....

Comment: @Suddev I created a color value (`blue`). How do I change the transparency of this color by the value name `blue` and not the hex value? Like in hex you would add `80` to the front of the hex to give it an opacity of 50%. How can I add `80` in front of the color name `blue`?

Comment: @RajSharma How do I do that in XML, like in the situation where I might need to use `blue` in `android:endColor=""`?

Comment: Are you trying to override blue? And include transparency?

Comment: I would just do this in style themes and use that theme. Can u try that ?

Comment: @Suddev Without using the color xml value name, I can do `#80002eff` to give the blue a transparency of 50%. How can I do `#80@color/blue` (obviously wrong, but you get the point)?

Comment: You can't do that, at least not in XML. You would have to create two colors.

Comment: @user5213685 - got your question clearly now, set the color & use themes to set the opacity.

Comment: How would I use themes?